# what's the difference between save() and persists() methods in hibernate regarding with cascading?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

[image]

```
                                     EER Diagram
```

***Please note that course entity is not related to this question**

Here I use save() method to save an object of Instructor to  the database.[Instructor and InstructorDetails have a relationship of cascading allowed one to one bidirectional ,so saving the instructor object will save the instructorDetails object too] .In that case I got an **error of object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing**.But when I use the persists() method that doesn't came.**So but when I change the cascading type to CascadeType.ALL It was okay with the save() method too.But you can see I just removed the cascade type of REMOVE only in the following code ,so how it's going to be affected to the method like save() ?**

**Instructor Model class**

public class Instructor{

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
//Here you can see I just only neglected the cascade type of REMOVE only 
@JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
private InstructorDetails instructorDetail;
//
//
```

}

**InstructorDetails Model class**

public class InstructorDetails{

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy ="instructorDetail",cascade = 
{CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH} )
//Here you can see I just only neglected the cascade type of REMOVE only 
private Instructor instructor;
//
//
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`persist()` makes a transient instance persistent. However, it does not guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time. `persist()` also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries.

`save()` does guarantee to return an identifier. If an INSERT has to be executed to get the identifier ( e.g. "identity" generator, not "sequence"), this INSERT happens immediately, no matter if you are inside or outside of a transaction.
You can fine more information on [Hibernate Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/) page, point **11.2. Making objects persistent**

Comment: I saw this answer in several other places too,but still I don't get it,If you really know what's happening there, then please explain it using my code or from an example.

Comment: When `save()` is used, it will generate an identifier and attach to the Object before it saves the object to the database, that's why it fails to save Instructor because of the `instructor_detail_id` column that is FK because it doesn't cascade to the child. only Parent is saved/inserted in the table. However, persist accomplished the task of saving both Parent and Child in one call.